# link a cartridge SKU to a FormField on a product page

Tags: python, html, django, mezzanine, cartridge

Hello my dear programmers,

i am trown into the deep with this project.
i need to build a e-commerce website but a little bit different, this person does not want a checkout cart but a contact form underneath every product with a field for:
name
product
textfield

we need to make it so the SKU of the product on that page gets inserted in the product field.

maybe there is a way to do it with a url instead, that it automaticly pastes the products URL in a textField.

i hope someone can give me some directions i need to look in or some documentation to read.

Django 1.10
Mezzanine CMS
Cartridge shop
python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, you can define URLs with regular expressions (as I'm sure you know). So a URL for a product page might look something like this:

`url(r'^product/(?P<sku>\d+)$'`

When the view is called from this URL, the sku is passed in as a keyword argument to the view. Then, when the template is rendered from the view, you can pass the keyword argument in as a variable:

`{{ sku }}`

This variable should automatically be included if extending a DetailView (otherwise use `get_context_data`).

Therefore, with a little Django templating (perhaps even Javascript), it should be a breeze to prepopulate form fields in your front-end templates with the SKU.

Here are some helpful links:

[Django documentation: passing keyword arguments to views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options)

[Django documentation: using a variable in a Django template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables)

[Django documentation: get_context_data in class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)